# Laravel : send data to a controller method with a POST request

Tags: forms, post, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I set a nested resource like this in my `routes.php` file :

```
Route::resource('channels','ChannelsController');
Route::resource('channels.posts','PostsController');
```

and so when i want to show all posts on a given channel I would get the channel id form the URI : 
`GET /channels/{channelId}/posts` with the method :

```
// PostsController.php
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 * GET channels/{channelId}/posts/
 * @return Response
 */
public function index($channelId)
{ 
      ...
}
```

but when i want to POST, the channel id will not get passed to the store method

```
// PostsController.php
/**
 * Store a newly created post whithin a channel
 * POST channels/{channelId}/posts/
 * @return Response
 */
public function store($channelId)
{
      ... // $channelId is not set
}
```

I know there's a solution, passing the data with a hidden field in the form, but it is not secure since anyone can edit it and post the wrong id.
Please let me know, if you have any solution.

Comment: `$channelId` not being set in the `PostsController::store()` method does not make sense. It has to be set based on what you've shown for your routes, controllers, and urls.

Comment: Also, consider that the url your form posts to is just as vulnerable to modification as your form inputs. Everything should be validated server side to make sure the input makes sense.

Comment: Since it is a resource controller, `store` is using POST as http verb.

Comment: Try read about (Route Model binding)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I found the solution in Laravel [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#opening-a-form) itself, here is it so that everyone can take advantage from :

`Form::open(array('action' => array('Controller@method', $user->id)))`

- the variable `$user->id` is passed as argument to the method `method`, also this last one should recieve an argument as well, like so :  `method($userId)`